# Insert fails with first error, not all errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

As has been the way for a long time an insert error returns the first message, not all messages.  The following returns 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric.' when in fact there are two invalid values. After fixing the value for columnB we then see an error for columnC.  How to see all messages on first attempt?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
[columnA] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ColumnB] decimal(2,0) NOT NULL,
ColumnC int null
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]
       ([columnA]
       ,[ColumnB]
       ,ColumnC)
 VALUES
       (23,
       'a',
       'b')
```

Comment: You cannot (at least using an `insert`).  SQL Server stops at the first failure.

Comment: Options besides an insert then?

Comment: The only way to insert data into a table is to use INSERT (or MERGE), so there are no other options in T-SQL, unless you want to write something that validates it beforehand

Comment: Remember that SQL Server can work with *large* data sets. You may disagree with the decisions of the SQL Server developers but they decided that since they know that the `INSERT` is going to fail, there's no point potentially engaging in *lots more work* to detect any further errors.

Answer (score 0):

To do that type of thing you can use separate `try-catch` blocks in your scenario since it only has a few fields.

```
begin try
    insert into table_1
    (columnA)
    values 
    ('any value')
end try
begin catch
    select ERROR_MESSAGE()
end catch

begin try
    insert into table_1
    (columnB)
    values 
    ('any value')
end try
begin catch
    select ERROR_MESSAGE()
end catch

begin try
    insert into table_1
    (columnC)
    values 
    ('any value')
end try
begin catch
    select ERROR_MESSAGE()
end catch
```

Comment: http://www.sqlusa.com/articles2008/trycatch/ 
You can refer this site for further information